# regex expression for any letters, space, Apostrophe and blank input

Tags: regex, validation

this is the current expression i'm using, but when i input a value it only accepts 1 letter
when i input more than 1 i get an invalid input.

```
"regex":"/^(?:[a-zA-Z\ \']{30}|)$/",
```

what type of expression might be suitable for the input that i'm looking for?

ex:

John Franklin

or

(blank input)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more as to what you mean?

For example, what do you mean in the examples? Are parentheses allowed, are you trying to accept / deny all text that do not meet your requirements, or only selecting all parts of the text that are valid...

Comment: it doesn't look like a valid regex - you have an incomplete "or" (the `|`)

Comment: regex expression for any letters, space, Apostrophe and blank input

Comment: I think that's an attempt to match blank lines - which would be solved by `(^...$|^$)`. Not the most compact form, certainly, but clear in intent here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
/^([a-zA-Z ']*)$/
```

I've [tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/t4vM6/1) and it appears to fit your needs.

For clarity, `*` means 'match 0 or any number of characters', which from my testing, satisfies your 'blank' requirement.

Comment: `\s` denotes whitespace, which is not limited to spaces, but includes other forms of whitespace, such as tabs.

Comment: It isn't necessarily wrong; that may be what the OP really wants. I was just "enriching the explanation."

Answer (score 2):

Letters, space, apostrophe, or blank:

```
/^[A-Za-z ']*$/
```

If you are capping it at 30 characters, then replace `*` with `{0,30}`. In some regex flavours you can omit the `0` and use `{,30}`.

Answer (score 0):

`x{30}` means "exactly 30 instances of `x`". It sounds like you actually want *up to* 30 characters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\ \']{0,30}$/
```

(using the {*m*,*n*} notation, meaning "between *m* and *n* instances").

Comment: @telexper That would be the `0` case.